# How to display a MPAndroidChart in Logarithmic scale, in Android?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there a simple way to display `BarChart` in logarithmic Y scale? I'm thinking of extending `BarChartRenderer` `drawDataSet` method but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logarithmic scale is **not possible by default.**

If you are considering to implement the feature yourself, I would start by

- looking in to the **matrices** used for transforming between values and pixels
- looking at the code that actually renders stuff to the screen